# What is the meaning of this sentence 'bouncing on the balls of her feet.'?

Tags: word-meaning, harry-potter

I'm reading 'Harry Potter'

"You do not usually take this class, is that correct?"

"Quite correct," said Professor Grubbly-Plank, hands behind her back and **bouncing on the balls of her feet.** "I am a substitute teacher standing in for Professor Hagrid."

What is the meaning of this sentence 'bouncing on the balls of her feet'?
and I don't konw what 'ball' is? baseball? football?

Comment: Did you try and look for dictionary definitions of "bounce" and "balls of the feet"? Your question is perfectly answerable with a dictionary.

Comment: Looking for images can often help as well. Such as [here](http://www.jimlangley.net/crank/cleat1.gif) or [here](http://www.footankle.com/pain-in-the-balls-of-your-feet-can-kill-a-vacation/)

Comment: / fluffy Of course, I looked for dictionary already, but I found no clue relating to 'foot' with 'ball'.
surely, there will be a reason why you native english speaker says 'that part' of foot as 'ball',
sorry for my poor english skill level. T.T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idiom is ***balls of someone's feet.*** The area where the toes end. It's a common gesture done by many.

Bouncing on the balls of her feet means she was going up and down using that part of her body. :)

Answer (score 0):

It is a gesture that people make when they are excited or impatient. They are standing on the ground while they use their toes to bounce up and down.